# Counting number of NULL values in each row using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, count, null

I'm new to QGIS and am trying to figure out how to count the number of NULL in each row and reflect the number in a new field.

How would the expression look like?

The image is what the table looks like.

[image: The table]

Answer (score 5):

Simple and stupid approach...

If your attribute table has fields with names `"Field_1"`, `"Field_2"`, `"Field_3"`, and so on;

```
("Field_1" IS NULL) + ("Field_2" IS NULL) + ("Field_3" IS NULL) + ... + ("Field_n" IS NULL)
```